# Get state value by a dynamic key in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say in my component I set the state like so:

```
this.setState({
      test: "value",
      othertest: "value"        
});
```

If, elsewhere in my code, I have an array containing the keys for these values, ie- `keys = ["test", "othertest"]` how can I loop through this array to find the value of the corresponding state value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**State is an object**, so you can access any value by:

```
this.state[key]
```

Use any loop `map, forEach` etc to iterate the `array` and access the value by `this.state[key]`, like this:

```
a.forEach(el => console.log(this.state[el]))
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let state = {a: 1, b: 2};
let arr = ['a', 'b'];

let values = arr.map(el => state[el])

console.log(values);
```

Comment: that won't work for functional components

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to array access syntax, you can access a property of an object (like state), using a variable:

```js
let state = {a: 1, b: 2}
let myKey = 'a';

console.log(state[myKey]) // 1
```

So to get all the values for an array of keys, map over your array of keys and retrieve the value of the state at each key.

`let values = keys.map(key => this.state[key])`