# How to pass a string as an argument and attach it to a REACT state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to pass a string as an argument that finishes this.state and builds out HTML. I create an arrow function below the render() and above the return

```
const createHtml = (name, stateProperty) => {
  return (
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <p>{this.state.stateProperty+'_x'}</p>
    <p>{this.state.stateProperty+'_y'}</p>
  )
}

createHtml('Jon', 'company')
// the result should be 
//<h1>{Jon}</h1>
//<p>{this.state.company_x}
```

I've tried different variations and none worked or came up 'Cant read property'

```
<p>{this.state.${statePropety}+'x'}</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing state by dynamic key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985321/get-state-value-by-a-dynamic-key-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a `{}` block are regular Javascript expressions.

Therefore, you must write them as regular Javascript, not JSX.

You want `this.state[stateProperty + 'x']`.

Answer (score 1):

this is a functional component so you have not a state , but props so :

```
 const createHtml = ({name, Property}) => {
  return (
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    <p>{Property+'_x'}</p>
    <p>{Property+'_y'}</p>
  )
}
```

and use it somewhere :

```
<createHtml name='Joe' Property = 'something'  />
```